# "develop awareness of", "develop an awareness of" or "develop the awareness of"?

Tags: articles

Tell me please if I should use any article before the word *awareness* in the following sentence.

> Many don't realise that they arch their lambar spine during the squat, so it is crucial to develop (**an**/**the**) awareness of it to avoid injury.

I lean towards the use of *the*, but I heard natives say it with *a* and without any article.

Comment: Speaking personally, the definite article would be my last choice. I'd use *an*, then nothing, then *the*. Alternatively, you could use a personal pronoun (*their*).

Comment: Why does "the" sound not that well?

Comment: Using it reminds me of using the definite article with *The Force* from Star Wars: *Reach out with the awareness*, so to speak. Except that *awareness* isn't a proper noun, and you can't point *at* it and say, *Look at that awareness!* in the same way that you could point at a door and say, *Look at that door!*. *Awareness* just isn't amenable to the definite article in the same way that other nouns are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awareness is an abstract noun. It is not something that is countable, or which exists in a concrete sense. It is therefore most common not to use any article at all.

That said, the use of articles with abstract nouns is not straightforward.

Abstract nouns *can* be used with an indefinite article (a/an). Few native English speakers would understand the difference between 'an awareness' and 'awareness', let alone English learners, but there is an explanation [here](https://doclecture.net/1-7034.html) and [here](http://www.corollarytheorems.com/Grammar/Archive1/question9.htm). In essence, they are largely interchangeable, but with, perhaps, a slight additional specificity when using the indefinite article which is similar to saying 'a kind of'.

In your sentence, saying

> "so it is crucial to develop **a kind of** awareness"

would not be accurate. You want people to have general awareness, not a specific kind of awareness. So I would probably lean towards no article if I was being extremely pedantic. But either option is fine.

It is also possible to use abstract nouns with the definite article when referring to a particular instance of the noun. In your sentence that is not be appropriate.

[PS. As @Jason Bassford notes, 'force' is an abstract noun too, but in the universe of Star Wars, 'the Force' is a proper noun referring to a specific type of force used by Jedi, and therefore the definite article is appropriate.]